# Is there any proper way to hide the printed JWT token from the console log when calling xcrun altool --upload-app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xcrun

I am trying to use the new **xcrun altool** to validate and upload my .ipa file to App Store Connect in a GitHub public repository. I would like to use the new *apikey* version of the command because I don't like to deal with *2FA*.

```
xcrun altool --upload-app --file $(find . -type f -name "*.ipa") --apiKey $AC_PRIVATE_KEY_ID --apiIssuer $AC_ISSUER
```

Unfortunately this command's first thing to do is to print out the generated JWT token on the console which is not that great in case of a public repository. Is there any proper way to prevent this behaviour? I would like to keep all the other output of this command except for the token for obvious reasons.

The full output of this command when it succeeds is

```
Generated JWT: eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NoiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQeyJleHAiOjE1NzM4NTczNTMsImlzcyI6IjA5M2I3YTZhLTg...
No errors uploading './App/Actions.ipa'
```